# How to select same column twice with different format in Postgres Sql?

Tags: postgresql

I want actual column value along with truncated column value like below. can any one can help.

```
Select "sub1"."TimestampField","month_trunc1","month_trunc2" 
from (
   Select  "Id", date_trunc('month', "TimestampField") as "month_trunc1", "TimestampField" 
   from "Table"
) as "sub1", (
  Select  "Id", date_trunc('month', "TimestampField") as "month_trunc2", "TimestampField" 
  from "Table"
) as "sub2" 
WHERE "month_trunc2" = ("month_trunc1"+interval '1 month');
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify you example by using JOIN on the same table:

```
 SELSECT 
   "sub1"."mainfield",
   "sub1"."TimestampField" as month1, 
   "sub2"."TimestampField" as month2, 
   date_trunc('month', "sub1"."TimestampField") as "month_trunc1", 
   date_trunc('month', "sub2"."TimestampField") as "month_trunc2"
 FROM "Table" "sub1" 
 JOIN "Table" "sub2"
       ON "month_trunc2" = ("month_trunc1"+interval '1 month');
```

Comment: Note that postgres cant use aliases in ON clausule, so you have to replace "month_thrunc1/2" with full statement date_trunc('month', "sub1/2"."TimestampField")

Comment: i want actual TimestampField value and truncated TimestampField value **date_trunc('month', "TimestampField") as "month_trunc1", "TimestampField"**